# For Loop Stops after First Iteration

Tags: mysql, for-loop, php-7.3, laravel-6.2

I've got this for loop here that stops the loop after the first loop due to the value of `$due = 0`. If value of `$due` is anything other than `0`, the loop runs fine and everything works--problem is, this condition must always be zero. Bangin' my head against the wall on this one. Any ideas? Here's the loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $unpaid->getInvoiceQuantity($customer_id); $i++) {
        $each_invoice_id = $request->input('invoice_id' . $i);

        $whats_due = DB::table('invoices')
                       ->select('due')
                       ->where('id','=', $request->input('invoice_id' . $i))
                       ->first();

        $invoice_payment_total = $request->input('total' . $i);
        $inv_id_array = array('invoice_id' => $request->input('invoice_id' . $i), 'payment_id' => $payment_id,
                              'no_invoice' => false);
        DB::table('payment_applications')->insert($inv_id_array);

        $due = 0;
        if ($whats_due->due == $invoice_payment_total) {
            $due = 0;
        }
        if ($whats_due->due > $invoice_payment_total) {
            $due = $whats_due->due - $invoice_payment_total;
        }

        $update_array = array('due' => $due);
        DB::table('invoices')->where('id', $request->input('invoice_id' . $i))
          ->update($update_array);

        $payment_application_update_array = array('amount' => $request->input('total' . $i));
        DB::table('payment_applications')->where('invoice_id', $request->input('invoice_id' . $i))
                  ->update($payment_application_update_array);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the updates must be changing the invoice quantity, and making it lower than `$i`, so the loop condition is no longer met.

You should save the value in a variable rather than calling the method every time.

```
$quantity = $unpaid->getInvoiceQuantity($customer_id);
for ($i = 0; $i < $quantity; $i++) {
    // rest of loop
}
```